# How to include a local table of contents into Sphinx doc?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, restructuredtext, tableofcontents

How to include a local table of contents into Sphinx doc?

I tried

```
.. toc::
```

But that doesn't seem to have any effect: nothing is inserted in the document.

Basically I need links to the sections in the current page to be placed at a certain location of each page.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure this is what you're looking for, but the `.. contents::` directive may help.  By default, it'll give you the headings for the whole page, wherever you put the directive.  With `:local:` specified, it will generate a local TOC for the headings below where you put the directive (handy for sub-section tocs).

```
.. contents:: Table of Contents
    :depth: 3
```

More details here: http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#table-of-contents

Comment: `.. contents:: :local:` is the magic juice. When omitting the `:local:` flag, the Table of Contents is uselessly prepended by a link to the document heading. Moreover, all other headings are subheadings of the document heading and hence uselessly indented one level deeper than they otherwise should be. In short, `:local:` is all but mandatory for most use cases. (_I really wish `:local:` were the default, frankly._)

Comment: Does the `:local:` keyword still works? I can't make it function on recent version of sphinx, it seems to only work under H1 title, but not within sections.

Comment: As far as I know, yes.  I've got a test with it running under H2 in Sphinx 3.5.2.

Answer (score 12):

I had more luck with:

```
.. contents:: Table of Contents
   :depth: 1
   :local:
   :backlinks: none
```

The backlinks gets rid of the annoying links back from the headings to the toc.